# Creating windows bootable DVD

Tags: windows, brasero

I tried creating a windows 8.1 bootable DVD using Brasero (iso), the process completed successfully but it failed to boot from the DVD, it just goes straight to my windows desktop. How do i make a windows DVD on Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you alter the BIOS settings to boot from the DVD?

Comment: Yes, i booted directly from the DVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tools offered for Ubuntu.

**If you want to use a DVD follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).**

I usually prefer to use a **Flash drive**:

1. *Startup Disk Creator* - already built-in and comes with Ubuntu.
2. *WinUSB*:

64-Bit:
`wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_amd64.deb`

32-Bit:
`wget https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/freshlight/+files/winusb_1.0.11+saucy1_i386.deb`

To install run `sudo dpkg -i winusb_1.0.11+saucy1*`. In case of dependencies issues run `sudo apt-get -f install`

** Note: your current DVD/flash drive may be good. But sometimes there are problems with UEFI/new windows-based computers. Try to turn on Legacy mode via bios settings and make sure boot order is correct (USB/DVD).

Comment: I actually prefer USB myself but at this point it needs to be burned into a DVD disc. Anyhow, since brasero did not work, i will try out k3b. Thanks, am checking this as answered.

Comment: The so-called "winusb" always gives me error when trying to create a bootable usb, so far, i have not been able to use it to create a windows bootable usb.

Comment: what is the error message? did you try "Startup Disk Creator" ?

Comment: Startup Disk Creator only works for Linux distros. @guyromb